# Want to bring over many columns from another table to a table that has a column of matching values

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have two (2) tables in Power Bi and I wish to bring over several columns from a table that has a column of matching values (there are many columns that I don't need). What is the best way to do so? I tried DAX query but it only allowed for one column to bring over using the LOOKUP function. I tried to merge the queries but didn't quite understand how to get it to work as the table expanded did not match up to the values. Some help please for performing this operation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it with DAX, use Power Query to merge on the key column. This can all be achieved using the menu and options, no code required. This is the same as in Excel, so here's a [walkthrough from Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/combine-data-from-multiple-data-sources-power-query-70cfe661-5a2a-4d9d-a4fe-586cc7878c7d) that goes through all the steps you might need.Once you start using Power Query you won't look back. Good Luck!